# change textcolor of UIButton with stateselected

Tags: xcode, ios7, storyboard

I have tried to change my `UIButtons` textcolor when `UIControlstate` is selected/highlighted and it doesn't work, I have tried with storyboard and programmatically and I couldn't change the textcolor of my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```